# Upload file on server through rtmps+java

Tags: apache-flex, jakarta-ee, rtmp, rtmps

I need to upload file on server through flex GUI which send file on server with using rtmps protocol.

I tried to send on server just FileReference and request has performed, but on server side i got only empty ObjectMap. I know that I can user URLRequest, but I need exactly rtmps request.

My Flex code:

```
public function uploadFile(file:FileReference):void{
     NetConnection nc = new NetConnection();
     nc.client = this;
     nc.proxyType = "best"; 
     nc.connect(connectionURL, "3.0", "userName", "password");
     nc.call("uploadFile", null, file);
}
```

My Java code:

```
public void uploadFile(Object param) { // <-- param is empty ObjectMap
    log.info("Upload file.");
    // save file on server
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't know how to map the FileReference class to a java equivalent. In flex, get the ByteArray from the FileReference and send that to the server. Java knows how to deal with a byte array. You can do with it on the server as you please then.

Comment: Do you mean file.data? If so, I'm tring this way right now, and found one problem, that Java get class org.red5.io.amf3.ByteArray and i don't know how to convert it in something that i can write in file.

Comment: in your java function change the param type to byte[] and not Object.

Comment: I found another solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126842/convert-flex-bytearray-in-java-byte, but thank you for answer, it helpful.