# Convert Flex ByteArray in Java byte[]

Tags: java, apache-flex, red5, rtmp

I'm trying to upload file on server which send from Flex GUI with rtmp protocol.
I asked yesterday how to send file's data on server:  [Upload file on server through rtmps+java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108556/upload-file-on-server-through-rtmpsjava)

But now i have problem with how to convert org.red5.io.amf3.ByteArray in something that i can correctly save in file.

Cam some one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the array:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteArray.length()];
byteArray.readBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: Method getData() is not visible, because it's protected.